# Datepicker dropdown defaults to January 1940

Tags: 8, datetime

In a custom form, I have this date field:

```
$form['contact_information']['birthdate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => t('Birthdate'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

When I click on the field, the calendar dropdowns default to Jan 1940:

[image: Jan 1940 default]

I have added some Javascript to set the date automatically to today's date by default, so the calendar grid itself is correct, but the dropdowns are wrong.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    Date.prototype.toDateInputValue = (function() {
        var local = new Date(this);
        local.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() - this.getTimezoneOffset());
        return local.toJSON().slice(0,10);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-drupal-selector="edit-birthdate"]').val(new Date().toDateInputValue());
    });
});
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052187/5306408))

When I click the left arrow besides the dropdown, the dropdowns change (as expected) to last month, December 2016. It is just the initial dropdown values in this UI element that are wrong.

Is there a way to fix this, or do I need to open a ticket?

Comment: What is the Javascript?

Comment: I've added it to the post.

Comment: Normally the datepicker defaults to the current date. Just a wild guess, could there be anywhere on your site example code from this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746853/jquery-datepicker-set-default-date-for-the-calendar